# Plot3D with constraints

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the function

```
 fun[p_, q_] = ((-(1/2) + Sqrt[p^2 (1 + q)^2]/(p^2 + (1 + q)^2)) Log[
     1/2 - Sqrt[p^2 (1 + q)^2]/(p^2 + (1 + q)^2)])/
   Log[2] - ((1/2 + Sqrt[p^2 (1 + q)^2]/(p^2 + (1 + q)^2)) Log[
     1/2 + Sqrt[p^2 (1 + q)^2]/(p^2 + (1 + q)^2)])/Log[2];
```

subjected to constraint that `p + q <= 1`. It would be nice if the region/portion corresponding to equality is also highlighed.

Comment: `Plot3D[fun[p, q], {p, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{p, q}, p + q], Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Automatic}, PlotPoints -> 50]`

Answer (score 4):

```
fun[p_, q_] = ((-(1/2) + Sqrt[p^2 (1 + q)^2]/(p^2 + (1 + q)^2)) Log[
       1/2 - Sqrt[p^2 (1 + q)^2]/(p^2 + (1 + q)^2)])/
    Log[2] - ((1/2 + Sqrt[p^2 (1 + q)^2]/(p^2 + (1 + q)^2)) Log[
       1/2 + Sqrt[p^2 (1 + q)^2]/(p^2 + (1 + q)^2)])/Log[2];
Plot3D[fun[p, q], {p, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{p, q}, p + q], Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Automatic, None}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Cyan], PlotPoints -> 80, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: tricky use of `MeshShading`!

Comment: `Plot3D[fun[p, q], {p, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{p, q}, p + q <= 1], PlotPoints -> 80, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]` seems somewhat simpler.

Comment: @user64494  Since `RegionFunction` can't highlight the equality so here we avoid use it.

Comment: Think of `Plot3D[fun[p, q], {p, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{p, q}, p + q <= 1], PlotPoints -> 80, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {Red, Thick}]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Plot3D[fun[p, q], {p, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5}, 
MeshFunctions -> Function[{p, q}, p + q], Mesh -> {{1}}, 
MeshStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 50, RegionFunction -> Function[{p, q}, p + q <= 1]]
```

[image]